# how to convert and download data from webpage into PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

i am developing a web application using PHP Codeigniter, i want a code to display and download a data from web page into a PDF format.

Comment: What did you try yourself? StackOverflow is not a programming service.

Comment: You want to generate PDF dynamically or just want to download already stored PDF.

Comment: i have data in my database, using that data i have to create pdf file and download it.

Comment: Then you should Google on how to create a PDF in PHP (there are libraries and examples out there), try to do it by your self and then, if you get stuck, come back here and show us your code and where you got stuck. We need to see some effort made.

Answer (score 0):

Download [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) and Extract it to `application/third_party/` Folder

Create a new file in `application/libraries/` name it `M_pdf.php`

In `M_pdf.php` file

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

class M_pdf {

    public $param;
    public $pdf;

    public function __construct($param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3')
    {
        $this->param =$param;
        $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
    }
}
```

Then successfully integrated mPDF in CodeIgniter.

**How to Used,** 
Load the mPDF library in Controller as the controller below,

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cont_letter_pdf extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('m_pdf'); //load mPDF library      
    }

    public function pdf_download()
    {
        $data = [];
        //load the view and saved it into $html variable
        $html=$this->load->view('welcome_message', $data, true);

        //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
        $pdfFilePath = "output_pdf_name.pdf";

        //load mPDF library
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');

       //generate the PDF from the given html
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

        //download it.
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D"); 

    }
```

I learn this from the following url. You can also view the Tutorial from here as well.

https://arjunphp.com/generating-a-pdf-in-codeigniter-using-mpdf/